# React component does not re-render

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component called TOC. In TOC's render method is another component called StatusCard. Each StatusCard makes a GraphQL query and displays some data. I need the StatusCard(s) to update every x minutes. I'm guessing I need to re-render TOC because there could be many StatusCards on the page and I want them all to update at once.

After much reading and testing I have the below code right before TOC's render method. As you can see I have tried `this.setState` and `this.forceUpdate` but neither of them work. The cards never update even though data returned from the query is changing. This page is somewhat of a dashboard and shouldn't need to be updated manually by a page refresh. Is there a very simple way I can do this?

EDIT/UPDATE: If TOC is the parent component and StatusCard (child) is rendered inside of TOC, will calling `this.forceUpdate()` or `this.setState(this.state)` on TOC cause StatusCard to update? Keep in mind that nothing about StatusCard actually changes unless the GraphQL query is called and returns new data. So I'm wondering if a change in data might never make it to the page since the new version of StstusCard is the same as the old one in the virtual dom. Does that sound logical?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState(this.state), 5000);
    //this.interval = setInterval(() => this.forceUpdate(), 5000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how the API is consumed and how you're passing the data to the TOC component?

Comment: Hi @Paul. That would be tough because the whole thing is littered with company info. Basically, there's a "GraphQL" component in each Card component that does all the backend stuff. I just give it a query. Then the TOC pulls it all together.

Comment: Is your `TOC` component a `Pure Component` by any chance?

Comment: @mukesh210 I believe so. TOC renders a status card. The status card runs the query and outputs some data to the page. It's not very complicated.

Comment: I am not sure but if you TOC component is Pure Component, then it might be responsible for avoiding re-render of TOC every 5 second. Pure Component shallowly compares previous props and previous state with current ones and then decided whether re-render is required or not.